# Codeigniter Group By

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, group-by

I want to group items by a value but failed. I have an array and when try to use `GROUP BY` it only returns first row but I need all rows.

I have to get something like this:

```
Brazil
- Value 1
- Value 2
- Value 3

Italy

- Value 1
- Value 2
- Value 3
- Value 4

Spain

- Value 1
- Value 2
```

This is my foreach function which is on model file:

```
function live() {
        $data = array();
        $this -> db -> order_by('mins', 'desc');
        $this -> db -> group_by('country');
        foreach ($this->db->get_where('table_name')->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

And this is my view file:

```
<?php foreach($live as $l) { ?>
<div class="country_name"><?php echo $l['country']; ?></div>
<li><?php echo $l['value']; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

I made my research but couldn't find an exact sample here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by` is used to fetch aggregate data like the # of rows per country, etc., which is not needed here. You can "group" rows by countries in php:

```
$countries = array();
$this -> db -> order_by('mins','desc');
foreach ($this->db->get_where('table_name')->result_array() as $row) {
    $countries[$row['country']][] = $row; //group rows by country
}
```

You can then iterate the array like this

```
<?php 
    foreach($countries as $country_name => $rows) {
        print $country_name;
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            print $row['value'];
        }
    }
?>
```